# Why Does the paint not show up in layout mode but only texture paint

Tags: texture-painting

When I try to paint a dog in *Texture Paint*, it works, but when I switch to layout the paint disappears.

Comment: Has the dog got a material with the texture in it? And.. it's not being in the Layout workspace that matters... how is the view rendered there? Go for 'Material Preview'

Answer (score 0):

The Layout tab has different View settings than Texture Paint tab - if you want them to be the same, then change them to match. The default views are just examples for us of what is possible, but you can customize them how you want them and then save your default file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are in shading tab otherwise you can't see the colors and textures.

[image]

[image]